# Two theorems clashes with each other in this case, please see it

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

It says that linear span of every non-empty subset S of vector space V, forms a subspace of V.  all right; as we know that that subspace is being formed by the Linear combination of S; so we can definitely say that S is basis set for that subspace which is formed by the L(S); but we can’t restrict ourselves to not to choose Zero vector in our subset S, in case we choose that S which has zero vector in it, subspace will be still formed; yes, but when we will talk about the basis of that subspace we will have to look up on zero vector as an element of basis vector; and will have to accept it; as we know that basis set can never posses zero vector as it will become dependent ( because the set containing zero vector certainly can’t have all it field element zero, in its linear combinations, to acquire the property of independent set) but in the case of S we just discussed, that still remains a basis even when there is zero vector element is there. How is this possible?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of your confusion is simply that it is not true that $S$ is a basis of $\operatorname{Span}(S)$. The definition of $\operatorname{Span}(S)$ as the set of linear combinations of $S$ only implies that $S$ is a generating family, but since $S$ might not be linearly dependent it need not be a basis.

Comment: Does this mean that basis will be a set in which zero vector is excluded?

Comment: A basis is a *linearly independent* generating set. As you point out yourself, this means that a basis cannot contain the zero vector.